# Does Overall CTR obey asymptotic normal distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, asymptotics, ab-test

## Background

In business industry, I came across two different type of CTR metrics to measure our products. I want to perform hypothesis testing(AB test) for these metrics. However, I am not sure about my test statistics' distribution.

> Click-through rate (CTR) is the ratio of users who click on a specific link to the number of total users who view a page, email, or advertisement. It is commonly used to measure the success of an online advertising campaign for a particular website as well as the effectiveness of email campaigns.
> -- wiki

The general formular of CTR is $ctr = \frac{\mathrm{the \ number \ of\ click-throughs}}{\mathrm{the \ number\ of\ exposures}}$. It can be calculated over each sample point or over the whole sample.

## My Question

> Let's set a click through rate scenario. Suppose we have only two user on CrossValidated landing page. I opened it 4 times and clicked it 2 time while you opened it 7 times and clicked it 3 times.

- One metric is **uPVCTR**: Average of each user's PVCTR.  Mine PVCTR is $\frac{2}{4}= 0.5 $ and yours is $\frac{3}{7}$. $\mathrm{uPVCTR}= \frac{\frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{7}}{2}$
- The other is **overall PVCTR**: PVCTR = $\frac{\sum{clicks}}{\sum{exposure}} = \frac{2+3}{4+7}$.

Suppose each user is independent, thus each ones' PVCTR is independent. The distribution of uPVCTR is asyptotic normal. If we have control and treatment group, and we denote $\mathrm{diff} = \mathrm{uPVCTR_{treatment}} - \mathrm{uPVCTR_{control}}$. We can use $\frac{diff}{\mathrm{var}(diff)}$ to perform a two sample T-test.

**However, what's the distribution of **Overall PVCTR**? How to choose a test statistics for it?**

Comment: You can clarify the question much by giving the general formulas for the CTR metrics. Now your formulas contain fractions with constants. Also 2-3 sentences context about CTR will give this forum a clearer view on your question.

Comment: Edited, adding explanation for CTR. This is a general statistic problem

Answer (score -1):

It is clear that applying the ***log*** function to $CTR$ yields a variable which is likely to be normally distributed.

Define

$
\log(CTR)=\log(\# \; click\, throughs) - \log(\# \; exposures)
$

Still, $\log(CTR)$ is expected to vary with the hour, and over the weekdays.